# Function with type synonym

Tags: haskell, types, type-synonyms

Sorry for asking as potentially silly question, but returning to Haskell to do some conversion from one database package to a different one, I find myself a bit puzzled about how to do this properly.

In the `Database.SQLite3` module, there is an `execWithCallback` with type

```
execWithCallback :: Database -> Text -> ExecCallback -> IO ()
```

Now, the callback is defined as

```
type ExecCallback = ColumnCount -> [Text]-> [Maybe Text] -> IO ()
```

that is, a function with type `ExecCallback`
My silly test code compiles and runs correctly:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Database.SQLite3
import Data.Text

cb :: ColumnCount -> [Text] -> [Maybe Text] -> IO ()
cb  n cnl ct = do print $ cnl !! 1
                  return ()

main = do
  dh <- open "fileinfo.sqlite"
  execWithCallback dh "select * from files;" cb
  close dh
```

but then, what is the point of the type??? And, how do I specify that `cb` is an `ExecCallback`??

Comment: It can make type signatures shorter!!! And you don't need to specify that it is one; it just is!! But if you like, you can write `cb :: ExecCallback`. I wouldn't particularly recommend it though; writing it out makes it clearer. And you don't need so many question marks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Haskell, with `type` you define a *type synonym*. In your example that means that `ExecCallback` is just an alias for the type `ColumnCount -> [Text]-> [Maybe Text] -> IO ()`, they are interchangeable.

You could change the following lines

```
cb :: ColumnCount -> [Text] -> [Maybe Text] -> IO ()
cb  n cnl ct = do print $ cnl !! 1
                  return ()
```

to

```
cb :: ExecCallback
cb  n cnl ct = do print $ cnl !! 1
                  return ()
```

and everything would still work as is. It can make your code shorter and more readable.

One other good example is

```
type String = [Char]
```

[in `Prelude`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:String). I bet you normally use `String` instead of `[Char]` in most cases. But you're absolutely free to use either.

Another (completely unrelated) example is the [`conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.6.4) package where some [type synonyms](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.6.4/docs/src/Data-Conduit-Internal-Conduit.html#Sink) make a major difference:

```
type Sink i = ConduitM i Void
type Consumer i m r = forall o. ConduitM i o m r
```

For something that's a sink for values of any type `i`, `Sink i` seems way more readable than `ConduitM i Void`. Same for `Consumer`.

Comment: Another good example is `lens`, which has super-gnarly type synonyms. One of the simplest is `type Lens s t a b = forall f . Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t`.

Comment: @dfeuer ok, I am sure there are odd type synonyms out there, but I am happy to have learned how to sole this simple case :-) Anyway, thanks!